# How to set and get Root logger 's log level in jboss_log4j.xml in Jboss 5.1

Tags: logging, jboss

My root logger in jboss_log4j.xml  is like

```
<root>
  <priority value="${jboss.server.log.threshold}"/>
   <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
 </root>
```

How to get and set the priority value of root  from java code?